# How to change dropdown menu as a normal link

Tags: jquery, html, css, metro-ui-css

I am using metro ui css. http://beta.kenosys.in. how can i make the services menu to load a html file like using href in atag for large devices and act as dropdown on small devices.

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="app-bar-element branding " href="index.html"><img   src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
        <ul class="app-bar-menu place-right">
            <li active-link"><a href="index.html"> Home</a></li>
        <li ><a  href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li id="services"><a href="javascript:void(0);" ">Services</a>
                <ul id="s-drop" class="d-menu" data-role="dropdown">
            <li ><a  href="embedded_systems_design.html">Embedded Systems Design</a></li>
            <li ><a  href="">Website Design</a></li>
            <li ><a  href="fpga_design.html">FPGA Hardware Design</a></li>
            <li ><a  href="">PCB Design</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li ><a href="https://github.com/kenosys">Resources</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="app-bar-pullbutton automatic fg-grayDarker bg-white"
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you would post your code, but I'm guessing you could simply add an a tag to your nav?

Example:

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="YOURDESTINATION">Dropdown Item</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: thank you, and how should i make it work as default dropdown on small devices

Comment: Also adding an a tag does not seem to be working, it works if i write a .click function